# Appeal of closure of LGPL question on SO

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

I asked [Can I use Qt LGPL license and sell my application without any kind of restrictions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994053/can-i-use-qt-lgpl-license-and-sell-my-application-without-any-kind-of-restrictio#comment15996338_11994053) on Stack Overflow and it was closed by five community members. I don't think it should have been closed. I was [told](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994053/can-i-use-qt-lgpl-license-and-sell-my-application-without-any-kind-of-restrictio#comment15996338_11994053) to come here, to Meta, to appeal the closure.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com accepts licensing questions. Do you want me to move your question there?  Ah, never mind.  You already got (and accepted) an answer on Stack Overflow.  Don't really know why you need the question reopened.

Comment: @RobertHarvey can't you still migrate it after the fact?  Wouldn't that be the best course of action?

Comment: Thank you then.If i have further quetions i will ask them there,In case it is not agains the rules again.I didnt know we have a programmer section other than this one.

Comment: @Hossein Sorry for the mess. I just figured you might get a second opinion here and perhaps some more info. Good luck with your questions though.

Comment: @Bart:No problem at all.At least i now know where to post licensing related questions:).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not on topic for Stack Overflow, so no it shouldn't be reopened.  It might be considered on topic for Programmers.SE because they specifically okay questions on software licensing in [their FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq), but such questions are not appropriate on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6):

Licensing questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow.